# Correct usage of numpy.nditer?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to do an array operation with [numpy.nditer](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html), but don't get the expected result.

My code is

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = - np.random.random((2,2))
arr2 = np.random.random((2,2))
arr = np.zeros((2,2))
it = np.nditer([arr1, arr2, arr], [], [['readonly'], ['readonly'], ['writeonly']])
for a1, a2, a in it:
    a = a1 if -a1 < a2 else a2
print arr
print it.operands[2]
```

I'm getting all zero results in both `arr` and `it.operands[2]`, but I expected values from either `arr1` or `arr2`. What would be the correct way to assign values to `arr` in the iteration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing `a =` in Python will simply rebind the local variable `a`; it won't affect what `a` contains.

With `nditer`, the iteration variables `a1`, `a2` and `a` are actually 0-d arrays. Thus, to change `a`, use the (slightly odd) `a[()] =` syntax:

```
for a1, a2, a in it:
    a[()] = a1 if -a1 < a2 else a2
```

Note, though, that your whole code can be simplified greatly by using `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = - np.random.random((2,2))
arr2 = np.random.random((2,2))
arr = np.where(-arr1 < arr2, arr1, arr2)
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand why the example in the docs uses `addop(a, b, out=c)` instead of `c = a + b`...